# Possible to use alternate weather api with Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, layer, weather, wunderground

The Weather.com data in the weather layer is aggregated temps from the region and NOT direct weather station data.  The meteorologist where I work is complaining about how inaccurate the data is on our web site.

We're already using a paid Weather Underground account for the rest of our weather data, so I'd like to replace the weather.com layer with a layer using data from weather underground.

I'm not sure where to start.  Is the base code for the current weather layer available? Or does anyone have examples of using alternative weather data sources?

Comment: It seems like the Weather Underground API supports JSON responses: [see here](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs). It gives you a lat/long, with a bunch of data - so based on that you can probably just make this an array of markers and display it on the map.

Answer (score 0):

The WunderMap layer with the temperatures will be coming to the API and then you'll be able to access it with the other API data like Radar and Satellite.  If you have an immediate need, get in touch with us at Support and we can connect you with Business Development.  http://help.wunderground.com/